# AJAX HTTP error occurred Code: 200

Tags: ajax

I am using  Drupal 7.34, and I am facing an AJAX error trying to use autocomplete fields in my backend (e.g. file field sources, product reference).

After searching for solutions, I found similar problems and mashed up some suggestions by  disabling:

- Firebug in Firefox
- jQuery Update
- Devel
- JavaScript compression

I also updated all modules.

Nothing helped.

I always get a popup containing this error  message:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows.
>   Path: http://my-ajax-nightmare.com/shop/inline_entity_form/autocomplete/node/field_produkt/bundle
>   StatusText: OK

The page is being rendered as it should.

How can I fix the error message?

Comment: Did you get the answer?